# Creating HTML table with column and row headers

Tags: html, powershell

I have successfully scripted PS reports using the HTML snippets below to create the results into a table:

```
 $tableHeader = " 
 <table width='auto'><tbody> 
 <td width='auto' bgcolor=`'$blue'' align='center'>Server</td>
 <td width='auto' bgcolor=`'$blue'' align='center'>CPU</td>
 <td width='auto' bgcolor=`'$purple'' align='center'>RAM</td> 
 <td width='auto' bgcolor=`'$yellow'' align='center'>Disk</td>
 </tr>
" 
Add-Content $ReportPath $tableHeader
```

Then some script to return the required values into variables, before adding the results into the previous table.

```
 $DataRow = " 
      <tr> 
      <td width='auto' align='center'>$Computer</td>     
      <td width='auto' align='center'>$CPUValue</td>          
      <td width='auto' align='center'>$RAMValue</td>
      <td width='auto' align='center'>$DiskValue</td> 
      </tr> 
    "
    Add-Content $ReportPath $DataRow;
```

This works perfectly well, with columns on the top row, and the results below that. But now I am looking at adding an additional column heading to the left of the table, let's say we have "Computer1"; "Computer2" and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wish to add the results into the table separately and not at the same time as when the table is defined, as in the above example.

Comment: You may want to consider using [`ConvertTo-Html`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156817.aspx) instead of the approach described in your question.

Comment: I manage to work it out - I need to create a new "Data row" per row and populate that each time. Thanks - forgot about the ConvertTo-HTML option - will have a go at that too, but might be limited in terms of formatting.